# Strategy to combine RGB image (numpy array) and a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, image, pandas, numpy

My background is primarily working on R but now I am working on a project where I need to use python, hence this question.

My problem is relatively simple (I think): I have a set of RGB images in python represented as numpy arrays. I also have a dataset (which I have loaded as a pandas dataframe) with some characteristics which need to be mapped to the rows in the images.

Now, the challenge is that the index in the dataframe is not the same as the row number in the images; I can derive a calculation that would link the index on the dataframe to the row on the image, but I don’t know how to incorporate this information into the image itself, so that by "looking" at the image I can extract the characteristics in the dataframe.

In short, I think what I need is a way to join the information in the dataframe to the image.

Not sure if I have made it clear so let me know how to better explain the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example data, and some code attempt? It will be quite helpful to understand the question

Comment: this link provides info on how to write a question that is easier for Stack Overflow users to help you answer: [mcve]